# Adding OnTouchListener to each line of ListView in ListFragment

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

Actually I thought the `ListView` of a ListFragment would have been created in `OnActivityCreated`.

```
  @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ...initialize the namesList

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, namesList);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Then I access the `ListView` in `onResume` to add a `OnTouchListener` to each row in the list (=the children) However there are no children added to the ListView yet - even though they should be due to the code above in `onActivityCreated` one should expect.

```
  @Override
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ListView lv = getListView();
    int n1 = lv.getChildCount();
    for (int ii = 0; ii < n1; ii++) {
        View lineV = lv.getChildAt(ii);
        lineV.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    }

    }
```

So the last chance to add the OnTouchListener is in `OnListItemClick`. (since there are no children in the ListView before)

```
   @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    v.setPressed(false);

    ListView lv = getListView();
    int n1 = lv.getChildCount();
    for (int ii = 0; ii < n1; ii++) {
        View lineV = lv.getChildAt(ii);
        lineV.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    }

    }
```

But even here the `OnTouchListeners`  have still not been added to the displayed lines.

Only after couple of times touching some lines in the displayed names list finally the `OnTouchListener` have been added and intercept the touches.

But until then the normal `onListItemClick` catches the touches - which I just don't want to happen.

All I need is to add the `OnTouchListeners` to each line in a `ListView` from THE VERY BEGINNING when the list is displayed so I can do whatever I want instead of let the `OnListItemClick` handle the event.

(I actually want to drag the line around while pressing the line - `OnListItemClick` only starts AFTER the line has been untouched)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something similar before in terms of adding a listener to each row in a list view.

What you need to do is to create a subclass of ArrayAdapter.  Then in the getView() method, set your MyTouchListener as the onTouchListener to your view before returning it.

Answer (score 1):

Override onViewCreated and add your listener there

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ListView listView = getListView();
    MyListViewTouchListener touchListener =
        new MyListViewTouchListener (listView);
    listView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener); 
}
```